# Multiplying numbers in file by random numbers

Tags: 14.04, sed

I have a file containing lines like:

```
tree my_tree = ((t1:961.00,t2:902.00):961:00,t3:878:00);
```

which represents a tree structure with branch lengths. I want to multiply all branch lengths in each line, i.e. numbers after`:`, by (preferably unique) random numbers between 0 and 1. Also it would be great if there is any random number generator utility in which the distribution can be specified, say normal with given mean and standard deviation.

I know how to generate random numbers with, say, `$RANDOM` or `shuf` whithin a specific range >1. I also know how to replace a regex with sed in file `sed -i 's/:[0-9\.]+/My_RANDOM_NUMBER/g' my_file`. But I'm still struggling to achieve the task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use something like `perl` or `awk` that can handle arithmetic operations, rather than `sed` (which can only really do regular expression replacement).

For example, using `perl`

```
$ printf 'tree my_tree = ((t1:961.00,t2:902.00):961:00,t3:878:00);\n' | 
    perl -pe 's/:([0-9.]+)/sprintf ":%.2f", $1*rand()/ge'
tree my_tree = ((t1:918.95,t2:880.40):633.34:0.00,t3:648.35:0.00);
```

You can replace perl's `rand()` by another random library function of your choice - for example, using `Math::Random` from the `libmath-random-perl` package:

```
$ printf 'tree my_tree = ((t1:961.00,t2:902.00):961:00,t3:878:00);\n' | 
  perl -MMath::Random=random_normal -pe 's/:([0-9.]+)/sprintf ":%.2f", $1*random_normal(0.0, 1.0)/ge'
tree my_tree = ((t1:-362.08,t2:822.35):-254.87:0.00,t3:1158.46:0.00);
```

Comment: Is there also any way I can restrict the numbers generated from `Math::Random=randome_normal` to be only positive? i.e. numbers are drawn from the positive side of, for example, N(0,1) distribution.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to restrict them - but you could take the absolute value `$1*abs(random_normal(0.0, 1.0))`